# dbgHelp new version

Tags: c++, windows, dbghelp

I want to upgrade my DbgHelp version from 5.1 to 6.11 (i heard that 5.1 is kind of buggy) so I downloaded "Debugging tools for windows" because that's where the dbgHelp is supposed to be but when I look at what is in the directory ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib"), I find only DbgHelp.lib.
where is the DLL supposed to be? :)
oh... and how can I know the version of dbgHelp if I don't have the DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer copies it to the top install directory, c:\program files\debugging tools for windows (x86) on my machine.  Same directory where you'll find adplus.vbs and windbg.exe for example.  My version is a bit older, 6.10